# Do ergodic isometries have discrete spectrum?

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a metric space, $\mu$ a Borel probability measure, and
$T:X\rightarrow X$ be an ergodic measure preserving isometry.

Is $(X,\mu,T)$ measure theoretically isomorphic to a minimal isometry on a
compact metric space (equivalently it has discrete spectrum)?

I understand Krieger representation theorem states that ergodic MPT are
measure theoretically isomorphic to minimal systems on a compact metric spaces.
I would like to know if structure like isometry can be conserved.

The general question I am interested in is: do ergodic isometries have discrete spectrum?

Comment: @FelipeG, can you add a few words on the equivalence between minimal isometries and discrete spectra? These sound interesting but I am not familiar with either concept in the context of general metric spaces.

Comment: Sure, a theorem by Halmos and Von Neumann state that T is transitive (one dense orbit) and isometric, iff it is topologically isomoprhic to a minimal rotation on a compact abelian group iff T is minimal and has discrete topological spectrum. (topological because in this case the operator associated to the dynamical system is acting on the space of continuous functions. ) 
A good reference for this is An introduction to ergodic theory by Peter Walters. 